# $f (x) ∈ Q [x]$ is irreducible if $f (x - 1)$ is irreducible.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I think the Eisenstein Irreducibility Criterion can work, but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, then $f(x-1)=g(x-1)h(x-1)$. If $f(x-1)=g(x)h(x)$, then $f(x)=g(x+1)h(x+1)$.

Comment: The argument is either incomplete or incorrect without handling units. But it's a dupe of a FAQ anyway so should be deleted. Please don't add more dupe answers to FAQs.